# Indentation in ListView

Tags: android, listview, indentation

Hi 
Is it possible to have indentation in the list view. 
Like the first item comes as normal, the second item indented to left and the next item more indented to left..

Comment: Where are your list elements coming from?  Are you using a CursorAdapter to create the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like an [ExpandableList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)?

You can indent the items on your own in the [`Adapter.getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method but you would have to figure out what the identation would be. As far as I know nothing like this is built-in.